# Constant for HTML line breaks in C#?

Tags: c#, html

I have a function `ParametersToHtml()`. It converts parameters to an HTML string suitable for display on a page. It uses `<br />` in a bunch of places. Here is what that looks like:

```
private string ParametersToHtml() {
    var result = "";

    if (Parameters.Count > 0)
        result = Parameters.Name + ": " + Parameters.Value;

    foreach (var param in Parameters.Skip(1))
        result += "<br />" + param.Name + ": " + param.Value

    return result;
}
```

The `"<br />"` construct isn't terribly ugly, but it isn't pretty either. I know that C# has `Environment.Newline` for regular newlines. Is there a constant for `<br />`?

(Yes, I forgot to use a StringBuilder in my example `foreach`. Whoops.)

Comment: Create your own

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml I interpreted your comment as "The constant you are looking for does not exist, and so you should create your own."

Comment: It's not so ugly to use standard tags in your code that builds HTML. F.e. compare your code with ASP.NET MVC HTML helpers: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: What difference do you find between already existing and self-made constant, besides multiple project use

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml Suppose that in a decade, `<br />` is standardized to `<br></br>`. Or maybe it gets replaced entirely with some other weird construct. Who knows what will happen? Microsoft updates their constant to be correct. Meanwhile, everyone who hard coded the tag themselves into their own constant suffers. Lesson learned: use standard code wherever possible.

Comment: Not a big deal just make your own standardized constants and when standards change change your library if you don't want to recompile or change only the file and recompile.

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml You have a fair point. Would you at least agree that, if a standard library constant *does* exist, that it would be preferable to use the standard library constant over my own?

Comment: By the way, don't forget to call **HttpUtility.HtmlEncode** or **HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode** method for **param.Name** and **param.Value**.

Comment: If there is an existing library that gets frequently updated (not dead) I would certainly use it rather mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find a constant like that, but here is the next best thing!

```
public static class HtmlConst
{
    public const string Br = @"<br />";
}
```

Then just call it:

```
foreach (var param in Parameters.Skip(1))
        result += HtmlConst.Br + param.Name + ": " + param.Value
```

Comment: In my experience there's no need for the verbatim identifier `@`. But that can be becsue this answer is almost 6 years old and things have changed.

Answer (score 3):

why dont you add "@" at the begining of the string

```
foreach (var param in Parameters.Skip(1))
    result += @"<br />" + param.Name + ": " + param.Value
```

no need to `"\"<br />\""`

you can read more in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: or better yet `result += string.Format("@<br />{0}: {1}", param.Name, param.Value);`. Even better would be to use a `stringbuilder` with a foreach building upon a string.

Comment: Your answer doesn't refer to the actual need of the user(Already existing constant for "<br>" = HTML new Line).

Comment: `String.Format` uses a `StringBuilder` internally.

Comment: I  forgot to take the `\"` out of the paragraph below the example. It wasn't meant to be part of the question. I'm just looking for a constant for `"<br />"`, not `"\"<br />\""`. Sorry about that. Edited the question to make the explanation match the example.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I was talking about the `result +=` portion of this, whereas if `result` was `StringBuilder` you could use `StringBuilder.append` instead.